# How to make GET requests works in Postman and Google Apps script

Tags: json, api, google-apps-script, postman

The following works in Postman:

```
GET https://mainnet.incognito.org/fullnode
```

with Body -> raw of:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "jsonrpc": "1.0",
    "method": "getbeaconbeststatedetail",
    "params": []
}
```

The following doesn't work in Google app scripts:

```
function getBeaconState() { 
  const mainnet = "https://mainnet.incognito.org/fullnode";
  var raw = JSON.stringify({ "id": 1,"jsonrpc": "1.0","method": "getbeaconbeststatedetail","params": []});
  var requestOptions = {
  "method": "get",
  "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
  "body": raw,
  "redirect": "follow"
  };

  var beaconState = UrlFetchApp.fetch(mainnet, requestOptions);  
  Logger.log("I set the beaconState variable.");
}
```

It gets a 400 error, so it must be something I'm doing wrong but poking around hasn't gotten me very far.

Comment: Thanks, Tyler for your suggestion, unfortunately, that didn't work for me, I got the same error.

Comment: Yes, still 400.

Comment: I don't get 400 anymore once I renamed body to payload. `payload : raw,` @Josh

Comment: That works, even leaving headers as is. Thanks @TylerRake

Comment: @TylerRake why don't you make that an answer.